# Does index column help as refiners in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-search, indexed-column

I have a document library in SharePoint 2013 on premise.
I have added a 'Document Type' site column of Choice type in the document library. Now I will add 'Document Type' as refiners in the search page.

My document library will have many records(more than 20k). So if I add 'Document Type' as index column in my document library then will it help as refiner in a search page or not.

Should I add 'Document Type' as index column to improve the performance as refiner or it will not help as refiner?

Answer (score 4):

It should not affect the refiner since the refiner is working against the search index, not the list's index

Comment: Thank you for reply, so just to set column as index will not help in search as refiner.

Comment: No it should not impact the search refiner experience